# Cómo desbloquear campos con texto en un Textbox

Tags: c#

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Tengo este formulario, cuando selecciono en Comprobar me carga los datos de la base de datos en los Textbox en las dos categorias hasta ahí todo perfecto. El problema es cuando ya cargué los datos de una categoría y selecciono el segundo botón para cargar los datos me bloquea de nuevo los campos de la primera categoría que seleccioné ya con los datos que se buscaron y no quiero que pase eso,  sucede lo mismo viceversa ¿Que puedo hacer?

Este es mi código:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtedad.Enabled = false;
        txttrabajo.Enabled = false;
        txtedad2.Enabled = false;
        txttrabajo2.Enabled = false;
 }
protected void btncomprobar2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
if (txtsolicitante.Text != "")
        {
             conn.Open();

            try
            {
                dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                if (dr.Read() == true)
                {
                    txtedad.Enabled = true;
                    txttrabajo.Enabled = true;
                    txtedad.Text = dr["edad"].ToString();
                    txtempresa.Text = dr["empresa"].ToString();
                   }
                   }
            finally
            {
                conn.Close();
            }

        }
    }
 protected void btncomprobar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtjefe.Text != "")
        {
 conn.Open();

            try
            {
                dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                if (dr.Read() == true)
                {
                    txtedad2.Enabled = true;
                    txttrabajo2.Enabled = true;
                    txtedad2.Text = dr["edad"].ToString();
                    txttrabajo2.Text = dr["empresa"].ToString();
                     }
                         }
            finally
            {
                conn.Close();
            }

            }

        }
```

Comment: Deberías dejarnos más claro a qué `TextBox` hace referencia cada una de las variables. Y qué método se llama desde qué botón.

Comment: El problema lo tienes en el `Page_Load`. Cada vez que pulsas un boton, el formulario hace un PostBack y vuelve a desactivarte los TextBoxes

Comment: @Pikoh--Tienes razón lo modifiqué y funciona correctamente, Gracias!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intenta cambiar el page_load así:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
       txtedad.Enabled = false;
       txttrabajo.Enabled = false;
       txtedad2.Enabled = false;
       txttrabajo2.Enabled = false;
    }
}
```

De la manera que lo tienes en este momento cada vez que presionas un botón se va a ejecutar esta parte del código y por tal razón los botones siempre cambiaran su estado.

Te recomiendo que le eches un vistazo al cliclo de vida de las páginas en ASP.NET https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms178472.aspx

Comment: @ Weimar Yamit Moreno Perez-- Funcionó perfectamente, gracias